# How to have all the columns of a table by doing a disctint on a single one in with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, distinct, aggregate-functions

I have a table from my SQL Server database composed of a stylecode column and an image:

```
stylecode   images

CTWAI4-RC   https://dwk1ydkfsczz3.cloudfront.net/CTWAI4-3589-1jpg-90da2f9b-d942-49f5-85df-a5fae6a76934.jpg
CTWAI4-RC   https://dwk1ydkfsczz3.cloudfront.net/CTWAI4-3589-1jpg-90da2f9b-d942-4785-85df-a5fae6a76934.jpg
WSM6HW-RC   https://dwk1ydkfsczz3.cloudfront.net/WSM6HW-0090-1jpg-998a79f1-6ed9-4610-b30d-113745e37c59.jpg
WSM6HW-RC   https://dwk1ydkfsczz3.cloudfront.net/WSM6HW-0090-1jpg-998a7781-6ed9-4610-b30d-113745e37c59.jpg
WLY8OW-RC   https://dwk1ydkfsczz3.cloudfront.net//WLY8OW-0026-1jpg-b526d225-5ae5-44fc-b78b-d755a3d94ff6.jpg
WLY8OW-RC   https://dwk1ydkfsczz3.cloudfront.net/WLY8OW-1651-1jpg-0051b696-d786-4864-9466-75f90b96fa33.jpg
```

As you can see I have several times the same style, I would like to make a query on my table to have only the same stylecode and the address of the corresponding images.

So I made a :

```
select distinct stylecode from dbo.Y2_Images;
```

Which returns all the unique stylecode but I would like to have next to it the values of the corresponding images,

I made a

```
select * from dbo.Y2_Images group by stylecode;
```

but my error is:

```
Column 'dbo.Y2_Images.images' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

How to make the two columns have the same values by sorting the unique values of the code style?

Comment: *"but I would like to have next to it the values of the corresponding image"* isn't that just `SELECT stylecode, images FROM dbo.YourTable;`..?

Comment: If you have multiple images for each stylecode, you'll have to choose which you want to show. Sql server can't make that decision for you.

Comment: Yes, but it's going to take all my table, I want to have a unique style and the corresponding pictures @Larnu

Comment: If I want the first of each stylecode how do I do it? @HoneyBadger

Comment: What does "first" mean?

Comment: I was thinking of the first address in my image column that appears when I look in my table

Comment: What defines the "first" one? There's no (ascending) ID or date column in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more that one way to understand your question.

If you want distinct style/images tuples, then:

```
select distinct stylecode, images from dbo.Y2_images
```

If you want just one image per style, even if there are several distinct values, use an aggregate function such as `max()` or `min()`:

```
select sylecode, max(images) as images from dbo.Y2_images group by sylecode
```

If you want all distinct images in a single column when there are several, use string aggregation:

```
select stylecode, stringagg(distinct images, ',') as images from db.Y2_images group by stylecode
```